# How to resolve "Unable to open file (Truncated file)" error in an iPython notebook

Tags: python, validation, ipython, neuron-simulator, allen-sdk

I'm trying to follow the example of [brain observatory ipython notebook](https://alleninstitute.github.io/AllenSDK/_static/examples/nb/brain_observatory.html).

However, I became stuck loading the `nwb` file like below.

```
from allensdk.core.brain_observatory_cache import BrainObservatoryCache
boc = BrainObservatoryCache(manifest_file='boc/manifest.json')

data_set = boc.get_ophys_experiment_data(501940850)  # problem here
```

So, I opened the `nwb` file by [HDFview](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/).

All of the brain observatory `nwb` files were not opened except for `502376461.nwb`.

It threw the following error:

> IOError: Unable to open file (Truncated file: eof = 82280448, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eoa = 204046519)

When I tried to open the `502376461.nwb` in the ipython notebook example from allen, it worked!! But the others (`501940850`, `503820068`...) failed like above.

Comment: In what way did it fail?

Comment: IOError: Unable to open file (Truncated file: eof = 82280448, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eoa = 204046519)

Comment: It seems that it is corrupted file problem,  https://github.com/AllenInstitute/AllenSDK/issues/22

Comment: It was downloading problem which was caused by too big size nwb file and no checking process confirming complete of downloading files.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing the thread from github:

https://github.com/AllenInstitute/AllenSDK/issues/22

The files were partially downloaded or corrupted somehow.  No exceptions were reported during the download, so urllib must not have noticed a problem.

AllenSDK developers are investigating some sort of file consistency check and/or a different HTTP library.

https://github.com/AllenInstitute/AllenSDK/issues/28

If others run into this, you can delete the bad file and re-run the download function (`BrainObservatoryCache.get_ophys_experiment_data`).  Files are downloaded into a subdirectory of the BrainObservatoryCache [manifest file](http://alleninstitute.github.io/AllenSDK/_static/examples/nb/brain_observatory.html#Experiment-Containers), which defaults to the current working directory if unspecified.